# How can I access Session variables in code-behind

Tags: javascript, c#, session

In script I set Session.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.Pagination', function () {
        '<%Session["Pagination"] = "' + $(this).attr('id') + '"; %>';
        alert('<%=Session["Pagination"] %>');
    });
</script>
```

Alert works.

I can't access When i want to session from code-behind

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["Pagination"] as string))
{
    string Val = Session["Pagination"].ToString();
    Session["Pagination"] = null;
}
```

String Val equal to  ' + $(this).attr('id') + '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this way and do it if one have better way pleas tell me

Javascript function:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.Pagination', function () {
        PageMethods.NumPagination($(this).attr('id'));
    });
</script>
```

Code behind :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string NumPagination(string Num)
{
    Page Pagination = new Page();
    Pagination.Session["Pagination"] = Num;
    return Num;
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["Pagination"] as string))
{
    string Select = "1";
    Select = Session["Pagination"].ToString();
    Session["Pagination"] = null;
}
```

[LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/341573/JavaScript-How-to-Set-values-to-Session-in-Javascr)

Answer (score 1):

I used to put the value in the hidden variable and this will be accessible in code-behind, anyway the session object is active in code behind you can set the variable to session successfully.

Advantage:
Globally declared session strings are accessible in code-behind and you can use the variables by calling the property files

**ASP**

```
<asp:HiddenField id="session_obejct" runat="server" />
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('session_obejct').value = "Variable you want to set in session";
```

**C#**

```
session["SESSION_NAME"] = session_obejct.Value;
```

you can use other methods as well, I hope this will meet your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to the (server-side) Session from within client side code.

The `alert('<%=Session["Pagination"] %>');` works because it is executed server side first, reading the value of `Session["Pagination"]` and inserting that into the javascript source, before sending that source to the browser.

By the time the browser sees that text and interprets it as javascript, the server-side commands (`<% ... %>`) have been replaced. The browser wouldn't know what to do with them anyway.